# How to get attributes of dataframe X from a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe X with 58 columns, and a list of some of column names of X. I want to get a column from X using my list like X.my_list[index] but I cannot because my_list[index] returns the column name like the following: 'column_name'. However the only way it works is X.column_name. In short I need to get the column names from my list to use it on my dataframe X without '', e.g. X.column_name. How can I handle this?

Comment: you want to select some columns only from your dataframe.?

Comment: If you need to subset your dataframe and have just the columns that are listed in your list, you can do: X.loc[:,l] or X[l], assuming that l is your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following,

X["column_name"]

to get the columns in form of Series.

```
# Example
X = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, "A", 1.1], [2, "B", 2.2], [3, "C", 3.3]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
col_list=["a", "b", "c"]

for col in col_list:
   print(X[col])
```